# Invoking a python script from a PHP script

Tags: php, python

I am running a PHP web script locally for testing purposes through terminal with command: `php -S localhost:8000`.

```
<?php $command = '/usr/bin/python /Users/Jupiter/Desktop/NC/www/createHarbourContainter.py'; exec($command); ?>
```

I am trying to call this python script that exists in the same directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import os
import sys

save_path = '/Users/Jupiter/Desktop/NC/harbours/'
name = sys.argv[1]

def newHarbourContainer():
    os.makedirs(save_path + name)


def main():
    newHarbourContainer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This python script has `chmod x+` set to it.

I am able to run the python script from the terminal :`python createHarbourContainter.py`

What I am unable to do is get the PHP function `exec()` to invoke the python script. Help needed!

Comment: If you have that `#!/usr/bin/python` header, could you try running it without `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: it's your exec can work?  try  echo exec('whoami');and the php script has make dir permission.you should get the exec output to find reason.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use backticks ` to execute shell commands, so try this:

```
<?php 
`/usr/bin/python /Users/Jupiter/Desktop/NC/www/createHarbourContainter.py`
?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php for more info

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a solution:

`$output = shell_exec('python createHarbourContainer.py')`

And to get back an output into the browser:

`echo "<pre>$output</pre>";`

I was running the server in `PHP Development Server`.
Using bash command: `php -S localhost:8000` from directory where index.php is located.
The server was logging all input and output from browser interface.
I realized that when calling: `/usr/bin/python` from php the `PHP Development Server`would halt and open python interpreter.

And setting the whole path to the python script I wanted executed didn't work because the PHP script didn't have permission.

How this can help someone else in future.